# Can I assign result of expression to a variable in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can I assign result of expression into a variable and use it in another textbox expression? instead of repeat the expression 1 in the expression 2

as sample I want to show how many records for some condition in a column A, and show the percentage based on the total in column B

Thankssss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ReportItem class to refer to a specific item in the report:

In column B use the following expression:

```
=ReportItems!TextboxColumnA.Value/ReportItems!TextboxColumnATotal.Value
```

where **TextboxColumnA** would be your first column and **TextboxColumnATotal** would be the total for Column A.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! Appreciate it.